# Are the unexamined lives of others worth examining? [Copied from non-meta Stack]

Tags: discussion, chat

See the [non-meta question details](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/138/are-the-unexamined-lives-of-others-worth-examining/). Also, I believe some questions like this one can be better understood--a little informally--through the Meta; there are not "technical" tags available, and I do not have enough reputation to add them: epistemology, dialogue, social critique.

[Message to chat on a random site:] Hi there, can I help answer any questions?

→What is the meaning of life? If you do not really know, what purpose have you given your life? (It says "any questions.")

Kristen: Haha man I wish I had the answer to those questions!

→The second one you do, else you would've committed suicide by now; we would not be talking.

Kristen: I guess you're right and my answer would be to help people ;-)

→Can you be a little more specific, on what you mean?

→Else, I'll let you get back to Sisyphus' work.

→(I ask these Qs because I know 'the unexamined life is not worth living' and so I have an interest in those who do not examine their lives or even take them for granted.)

→But those who hear this laugh (do not care) because they grew up (in the environment) of The Cave.

→I contend that you, and they, are in a rut. You are stuck in something... (maybe this is the 'heat of moment.')

→Our environment does significantly shape who we are. Just write the A |3 C in a row. Then, write 12 above the middle character, and 14 below.

→(A) Do you see it?

→(B) Do you See it; do you see the light glimmering outside The Cave?

→I may never get to see The Sun; 'I know that I know nothing.' Yet, I will continue on. I will continue gazing from The Cave at the bits that I See radiating.

→If I am one of these people, should I examine the unexamined lives of others?

→(No need to respond at this point; I am **now** freewriting.)

→To start, to what end would this serve? Would the end change if this is actually a morally obligated duty to help those, in The Cave, in their chains?

→Is there another end that is more important for the practical case of prioritizing? Are the causes of extreme poverty worth greater presidence for this generation, else forever those who follow, until extreme poverty is razed.

→Epidemiologically speaking, am I simply committing fallacies in this Q: confirming beliefs without their opposers (high birth rate of those with lower or little income), fallacy of composition (?2), incomplete comparison (?3), appeal to consequences (?4) or confirmation bias (?5)?

→Is dialogue--for action--more important than getting a degree? Rather, will answers change how you live or what you do?

→ Is asking 'why' necessary for this?

[I was told to put this as an answer to the non-meta question, I don't think it's the best for the 'Q & A style format;' I do not necessarily want a definite "answer."]

Comment: Wait, what is this?

Comment: I feel this is *meta* in the colloquial sense, but not suitable for meta.philosophy.se

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it would be best fit for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium), as it appears you are looking to stimulate discussion rather than asking a specific, narrowly defined question. The Meta site is for questions about how the site works, not for philosophy itself.

> **Meta Philosophy Stack Exchange** is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Philosophy Stack Exchange rather
>   than discussing philosophy itself. It is separated from the main Q&A
>   to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to
>   ask how and why this site works the way it does. Meta is for:
>
> - asking questions about how the websites work
> - asking questions of the community
> - posting bugs
> - suggesting improvements
> - proposing new features

See [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) for more information.